# Hiding cmd.exe window when starting from c# code

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

I am running a cmd.exe process from within a winforms application. However I can't seem to get the console window to run in the background (ie not show on screen)

here is my code

```
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
si.RedirectStandardInput = true;
si.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
si.UseShellExecute = false;
si.Arguments = "/c";
si.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process p = Process.Start(si);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set CreateNoWindow to true.

```
si.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
si.CreateNoWindow = true;
si.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```